# MySQL repeated denials on multiple hosts

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, denial-of-service

I have tried everything I can think of...going from my localhost to another servers host (which also uses localhost since I am using ftp on their servers apparently), and I still keep getting the error: 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user '(censored)_zxq'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES) in /www/zxq.net/a/p/p/(censored)/htdocs/lib.php on line 6
Connect failed: Access denied for user '(censored)_zxq'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES)

I have tried multiple hosts with mysql support too...I keep getting that error and I know that my credentials are right. AND I have given permissions to the database as well to the user. Any suggestions? (ps. I censored the important information to me)

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$login = '792981_kputts';
$password = 'whatup4u';
$database = '(censored)_zxq_ireport';

//access
$connection = new mysqli($server, $login, $password, $database);

//executes a given sql query with the params and returns an array as result
function query() {
    global $link;
    $debug = false;

    //get the sql query
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sql = array_shift($args);

    //secure the input
    for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
        $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
        $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
    }

    //build the final query
    $sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

    if ($debug) print $sql;

    //execute and fetch the results
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

        $rows = array();

        if ($result!==true)
        while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($rows,$d);
        }

        //return json
        return array('result'=>$rows);

    } else {

        //error
        return array('error'=>'Database error');
    }
}

//loads up the source image, resizes it and saves with -thumb in the file name
function thumb($srcFile, $sideInPx) {

  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile);
  $width = imagesx($image);
  $height = imagesy($image);

  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($sideInPx, $sideInPx);

  imagecopyresized($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,$sideInPx,$sideInPx,$width,$height);

  imagejpeg($thumb, str_replace(".jpg","-thumb.jpg",$srcFile), 85);

  imagedestroy($thumb);
  imagedestroy($image);
}

?>
```

Comment: install a phpmyadmin to that server via ftp and try to login. If it also fails your login info is not good. And I think it isn't good even if you say it is.

Comment: Please log in to the DB as root and post output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR '792981_kputts'@'localhost'` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR 792981_kputts`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I did the "show grants" and it gave me a ridiculously long password: 81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B. Anyway, that only gave me a new error:Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/lib.php on line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message suggest that you are not connecting from **localhost** (127.0.0.1) but making a remote connection(  *user '(censored)_zxq'@'192.168.1.1'* )

When making a remote connection make sure that:

- all firewalls (client and server) have port 3306 open
- that mysql is configured for remote connections, by changing the bind address in my.cnf to 0.0.0.0
- that the remote user connection has privileges to connect.

Even if 192.168.1.1 is the IP from the server, it is still considered a remote connection, and steps 2 and 3 (sometimes also 1) have to be performed.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but my port is at 3306 and firewall is down. I switched back to local out of frustration (3 different hosts was enough if they all said the same thing) and the privileges are set properly. I should add that I am using MAMP over here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Now, it is Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/lib.php on line 8

Comment: Is mysql running? `ps aux | grep mysqld`

Comment: Yup! I have never used the command line method though...should I? I use sequel pro normally instead (and I can connect through that program)

Comment: Does localhost work if I am using MySQL on my computer, but Fillazilla on a remote server?

Comment: Try connecting with `127.0.0.1`instead of `localhost`, what happens?

Comment: Just tried that seconds ago...same error except with 127.0.0.1 in it instead of localhost

Comment: And if you run a very basic index.php with only a hardcoded line to connect in it?

Comment: I have an index.php. It imports this and an api.php. However, the error is being stated as coming directly from lib.php.

Comment: And if you not import any stuff, just 1 line in index.php with `$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'yourlogin', 'paswd', `database`);`

Comment: hmmm...I did as you told me and got 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/index.php on line 2

Comment: Hmm this works perfect for me: `$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '*****', '******', '***');
var_dump( $connection );`

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this...but still getting a parse error. Maybe there is something wrong with the mysql service on my computer (though it didn't work on the hosted accounts). What else can I do besides your original answer to check to see if everything is working?

Comment: still the same--- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/index.php on line 2--- for your example and ---Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/lib.php on line 8 for my implementation. I am using php

Comment: I you get a parse error, then you have not typed in the code correctly! Do you have any experience with php at all?

Comment: About 6 months worth. However, I specialize in c++...I know, I know. What am I doing coding php then. But somewhere along the line, I have not been able to setup MySQL properly because apparently nobody else is having this problem. I have spent literally 3 full days on this and multiple host services, but it just will not get past line 8 on the error. Something is seriously ary, even for someone with years of experience...

Comment: I think you should asked yourself: why I am not able to type 1 line of php code from a example, without getting a parse error? Has nothing to do with my sql. Please do a copy past of your 1 line of code?

Comment: <?
$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'ireport'); var_dump( $connection );
?>

Comment: how about: <?php $connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'ireport'); var_dump( $connection ); ?>

Comment: Well, that fixed the parse error, but brought this new one instead...from just one line of code: Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(censored)/index.php on line 2
object(mysqli)#1 (0) { }

Comment: My conclusion: your MySQL server is not running! Try again with `<?php $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ireport');